# flying on Mars is possible—next up is the solar system

Tags: phrase-meaning

How do I understand the phrase "next up is the solar system"? Literally, it appears to mean "the next step is flying in the solar system."  But Mars is exactly part of the system. So I wonder whether the phrase is logically acceptable.

What does the phrase mean?

> Scientific American tweeted:

First in flight: NASA just proved **flying on Mars is possible—next up is the solar system**

> Source: [Scientific American](https://twitter.com/sciam/status/1390999933042446338)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a tweet, so grammar can be loose.

The Scientific American says since we can fly on Mars now we will soon fly everywhere (else) in the solar system. Presumably only where there's an atmosphere, so some of the moons of Jupiter and Saturn. Jupiter and Saturn (and Venus) themselves are unlikely.

An expanded version still using the phrase "next up" but getting the planetary physics right might be

> Ingenuity flew on Mars. Next up: build helicopters to fly from rovers
> we land on moons of Jupiter and Saturn.

In reality, that's pretty far in the future.

Comment: OK thank you.  How would it be worded in normal settings like in this forum with ample space?